# php xml object compare

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I get data from an XML object in PHP and use the "==" operator, but we do not get equality. It seems like a very basic question, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Minimal example:

```
<?php
// Load the file
$xmlData = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<root>
<a>animalia</a>
<b>arthropoda
<parent>animalia</parent>
</b>
</root>";

$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);

//Extract the data

$x=$xml->a;
$y=$xml->b->parent;

// Test whether they are equal

if ($x==$y) {
  echo $x." = ".$y;
}
else {
  echo "'".$x."' does not equal '".$y."'";
}
?>
```

This gives me the result: 'animalia' does not equal 'animalia'

Note, if I write either

```
print_r($x);
```

or

```
print_r($x);
```

I get the output: SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => animalia )

So the question is, why these are not considered equal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `trim()` them both and try again.

Answer (score 0):

[trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

```
<?php
// Load the file
$xmlData = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<root>
<a>animalia</a>
<b>arthropoda
<parent>animalia</parent>
</b>
</root>";

$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);

//Extract the data
$x=$xml->a;
$y=$xml->b->parent;
// Test whether they are equal
if (trim($x)==trim($y)) {
  echo $x." = ".$y;
}
else {
  echo "'".$x."' does not equal '".$y."'";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
animalia = animalia
```

Read About [XML Whitespaces](http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/XML_Whitespace)

Comment: Thanks that worked for me, also on the real example which is a little more involved. I guess that the trim command transforms them into strings too, which is also important. Thanks again.

Comment: @TimX, welcome dear glad to help you .. 
if any of the answer is helpful for you don't forget to up vote that answer  Thanx...

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing two strings, you are comparing two different nodes ( `<a>animalia</a>` vs `<parent>animalia</parent>` ).

They are two different `SimpleXML` objects.

To compare node values, cast objects as string:

```
if( (string) $x == (string) $y )
```

or:

```
if( $x->__toString() == $y->__toString() )
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explaination and the method which worked on my min example. 
My real example also generates white space so I needed to trim, as Manjeet Barnala suggested, and I guess this also transforms them into strings as a byproduct.

Comment: Yes. `trim` and other string methods cast the object as string. When a object (not only SimpleXML objs) has a `__toString()`, method, it is called when necessary.